# How to use jquery to setup a series of select controls so that only one can be used at a time?

Tags: jquery

I have a series of select controls for muffler types on motor bikes, one for 12" pipes, one for 14" pipes and so on (there can be up to 5 or 6 different types) 
I need to set this up so that a user can only select 1 item from all the select controls.

- any one but only one of these selects needs to be required
- if a selects a muffler in one control, then tries to select a muffler in another control all other selects should reset to no option.
- ideally only the one select that gets populated is submitted.
- there can be other select controls for other attribute types that should NOT be included.

The select controls look like:

```
<select 
    name="option[436]" 
    uo_sku_display_sku="0" 
    uo_sku_display_stock="0" 
    id="input-option436" 
    class="form-control muffler-type-control" 
    data-option-id="52">
        <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
        <option value="826" >option 1</option>
</select>

<select 
    name="option[439]" 
    uo_sku_display_sku="0" 
    uo_sku_display_stock="0" 
    id="input-option436" 
    class="form-control muffler-type-control" 
    data-option-id="53">
        <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
        <option value="826" >option 1</option>
        <option value="827" >option 2</option>
</select>

etc...
```

The 2 known pieces of data I can use to identify these types of fields are the data-option-id & the muffler-type-control class.

Not really sure where to start with this, maybe 'find' all selects in the form that have the data-option-id attribute with a value between 29 & 54 [the ids I would be looking for]

not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do

```
$('.muffler-type-control').on('change', function(){
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  $('.muffler-type-control').val('');
  $(this).val(selectedValue);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xz1xb0dc/

Comment: Though I would suggest looking into having a master/detail setup where you have two select boxes. The first being the type (like 12 inch, 14 inch, etc) and the second being the available values for that type.

Comment: unfortunately I'm dealing with an opencart plugin - display options are limited